# Appsee: How i can hide title of alert for appsee analytics

Tags: ios, appsee

I am using Appsee and using their video recording in my app.
I show an alert with confidential information. I know that I can hide the alert in appsee while using

```
+(void)markViewAsSensitive:(UIView*)view
```

and it's working. 
However, this API doesn't remove the title and the message for the sensitive alert from the timeline.
See the attached
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeOMD.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact Appsee's support at support@appsee.com.

Meanwhile, you can use `[Appsee pause];` before the alert and `[Appsee resume];` after the alert. See [docs](https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/api?section=video).
In order to be aware of the alert, you can send a custom event with the details you want to be displayed in Appsee via `+(void)addEvent:(NSString*)eventName`. See [docs](https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/api?section=events).